# How to add a physical connections to Cisco CSR 1000 in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cisco, amazon-vpc

I deployed 2 Cisco CSR 1000 routers in one VPC-1 at a region A, and at region B I deployed another one.
I would like to make a physical connection between these 3 routers.
Also, I tried to ping between these routers and it was successful which I don't understand because there are no physical connections between them.

What I want to make here is a scenario where I have 3 interconnected routers with their interfaces, each interface has a physical connection with a given router, and so on.

For the interfaces, only one interface `GigabitEthernet1` with the address of each router, and there is also `VirtualPortGroup0` interface.

`Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status          Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.31.34.123   YES DHCP   up                  up
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.35.101  YES NVRAM  up                  up`

Comment: You want to make a "physical connection"? You mean run a cable? Or do you want to have them run in the transit VPC pattern, routing data between the two regions? I've read the docs and watched the youtube videos, my impression is you need to set up a VPC tunnel between the two CSR appliances. We don't really have enough information to help you here, please edit your question to add a more precise question and relevant configuration information. If this is for production use you should consider a Cisco support contract, as the marketplace appliance doesn't seem to include any support.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I meant kind of cable between routers I know it is not real link but I need to measure the loads using the capacity of that link.

Comment: @khalildz34 you appear to be using two different accounts.  Please read [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: The Cisco CSR-1000v is a virtual router running on a virtual machine with a virtual network interface on a virtual LAN (VPC).  They don't have physical connections to each other. They can ping each other for the same reason two EC2 instances can ping each other -- they're connected to a network that allows it, and from your perspective, that network behaves like any other Ethernet network.  It remains unclear what you are needing to accomplish, or your purpose for using these routers (which can have very high license fees -- so you also need to be sure you understand what you are purchasing).

Comment: Why exactly are you using the CSR? What exactly are you trying to achieve, big picture? The main reason to use this appliance is in an enterprise level multi-account system, especially where you need an encrypted connection to your on-premise data center, otherwise there are often simpler approaches. AWS Re:Invent starts in a few days, new features are often released there.

Comment: @Tim I will try to explain the whole idea. I'd like to build an IP layer lets say with 4 interconnected routers where the capacity of their links are known (let's say 1Gbps), then I will create a functional layer under the IP layer that connects VNFs (set of network functions like FW, DNS ..etc). One or two those network functions are connected to these IP routers. Assume we send a traffic from an src to dest that satisfy a given service chain (FW, DNS) which are VNFs. The purpose of this is to measure loads of IP links whether they got overloaded after having a traffic around.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot what If I create VMs that host CSR-1000v in another VPC?
Please, refer to the whole idea which I just explained above.

Comment: You've still given us a technology view of what you're trying to achieve. If you have a business level view we might be able able to suggest ways to achieve it. Looks like what you're doing is some kind of testing of AWS? Sounds like you've achieved your aim in your anwer, but I still wonder if it's an expensive overkill.

Comment: @Tim no, actually it is not testing. I built a model which I have described above using an SDN/NFV modeling with more nodes and traffic. I got some interesting results which have been accepted in scientific papers. What I'd like to achieve here is to implement that model in real networks. Now SFC and NFV are a hot research topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution. 
When the Cisco CSR 1000v is booted for the first time, the router interfaces are mapped to the logical vNIC interfaces that were added when the VM was created. The figure below shows the relationship between the vNICs and the Cisco CSR 1000v router interfaces. So, using `show platform software vnic-if interface-mapping` I could display the mapping between the logical interface on the router
with the vNIC and the vNIC MAC address. Then, in EC2 I created a new network interface, and I attached it to my VM that runs the router. After that, I configured the new interface with the correct destination.

`Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status          Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       172.31.xx.xx   YES DHCP   up                  up
GigabitEthernet2       18.217.xx.xx   YES manual up                  up 
VirtualPortGroup0      192.168.xx.xx  YES NVRAM  up                  up`